# Could not install pandas in MacOs Catalina due to error "most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend"

Tags: pandas, macos

I'm using MacOS catalina and try to install pandas by

```
pip3 install pandas
```

But while I tried to import pandas, I got this error

```
python3 -c "import pandas"
```

This is error:

RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been facing the same issue. There quite a bit of info here:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15947

As I understand, its because your python version is detecting issues with the 'buggy Accelerate backend' in NumPy (NumPy is installed with Pandas).

I was running Python 3.9.0 and I was not able to fix. However I have been able to bypass the issue by using version Python 3.8.6. I used this guide to install 3.8.6
https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

See the part about

```
pyenv install
```

which I modified to:

```
pyenv install 3.8.6
```

After I restart, the debug in visual code now shows 3.8.6. I added all required modules again inluding NumPy and its working for me.

good luck